# What is the alternative in HarmonyOS for window.setDimAmount() in Android?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

To set the background dimness of a component like dialog box, in Android we can use the [`setDimAmount`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window#setDimAmount(float)) function.

```
dialog.getWindow().setDimAmount(0.5);
```

What is the alternative for this in HarmonyOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dialog.show();
Optional<WindowManager.LayoutConfig> configOpt = dialog.getWindow().getLayoutConfig();
configOpt.ifPresent(config -> {
   config.dim = 0.0f;
   dialog.getWindow().setLayoutConfig(config);
});
```

Just try to configure the attributes of the corresponding window after `dialog.show()`.